# JavaFX - Why does JavaFx create a primary stage instead of allowing me to do it?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I would like to create a class called EnhancedStage which adds functionality to Stage.
The problem is, javaFx creates the primary stage and passes it into the application, instead
of allowing me to create it. This way I'm not able to use my own class for the primary stage.
I don't understand why the system creates the Stage, and would I be losing anything by not
using that stage and instead constructing another one ?
Thanks

Comment: You could always create a [wrapper](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for the stage. I'm sure they have this system in place for simplicity

Comment: This is likely a design choice related to multiple factors, one been the fxml support and another been the complex setup process involved in starting a javafx app. This relieves the developer from having to generate all the boiler plate code over and over again as well us simply not trusting the developer to do the right thing (look at how new developers mess up Swing startup), but that's just guess work

Comment: I find it hard to see what you would do in a subclass of `Stage` that you could not do by calling API methods on the provided `Stage` (or by providing the functionality in some kind of utility class). Can you provide a use case?

Comment: @James_D I believe there are a few cases where adding behavior or state would come in handy, such as adding an `iconifyAndWait` method, or allowing stages to track scenes and switch between them in a managed fashion (go back/forward a scene)

Comment: @James_D I'm writing classes to extend JavaFX for functionality that is not provided but commonly needed in all apps. To do this I'm creating an enhanced version of a lot of UI stuff, like EnhancedTextField automatically selects all text on a click. For the stage I'm adding automatic saving of window position between app runs (prefences) and also code to make draggable undecorated stages (i.e. tool panels). I'm sure there will be more. The reason I'd like to extend stage and not use a utility class is to keep it clean and consistent and thus build my own JavaFX sort of. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use the stage which is a parameter of the [`start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start-javafx.stage.Stage-) method, then don't call [`show()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#show--) on that stage, just create your own stage and only call `show()` on your custom stage.  I suggest doing this inside the start method rather than via a runLater call from init.  I don't see any significant drawback in such an approach.

As to why a stage is passed in start, MadProgrammer's guess is as good as any: Simplifies life for programmers, removes some boilerplate code from basic apps and limits app startup coding errors.  For all those reasons, for most people, I'd generally just advise using the provided stage rather than creating your own.

Suggested approach if you need or desire to use a stage subclass for your primary stage:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StageTester extends Application {
    @Override public void start(final Stage systemStage) throws Exception {
        UserStage userStage = new UserStage();
        userStage.show();
    }

    private class UserStage extends Stage {
        FlowPane layout = new FlowPane();

        UserStage() {
            super();
            foo();
            setScene(new Scene(layout));
        }

        public void foo() {
            layout.getChildren().add(new Label("foo"));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Glad to see you that you still patrol the JavaFX tags. Can't say how many times your posts have helped me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from creating another stage and ignoring the one you get from the start method. There are number of ways to do this:

### Extend Stage and add your additional functionality

```
public class EStage extends javafx.stage.Stage {
   ... // Do your magic here
}
```

### or Extend Window

```
public class EStage extends javafx.stage.Window {

}
```

In either case, to use your new stage, you can just create it in the `init` method and use it in the start method, ignoring the stage supplied to you

```
public class ShowCase extends Application {
    private Stage mStage;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            mStage = new EStage();
            //mStage.impl_setPrimary(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        mStage.setScene(...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaFX architecture is based upon a **container** which manages the **JavaFX Event Loop** (on the JavaFX application thread) for your application (which is why the entry class for your application must inherit from `javafx.application.Application`).

Because JavaFX applications are container managed, you gain a few benefits:

- the container can inject JavaFX control references into your controller class instances via the FXML loader
- the container manages event propagation from the event loop all the way down to the target control and back up to the event loop again without complex event handling on your part

Of course, the event loop requires a top-level object for event propagation and this top-level object is the `Stage` object, which gets passed to the `start()` method of your Application object.